# Widget no funciona en TestFlight

Tags: flutter

Actualmente tengo un problema con TestFlight de Apple, este radica en que tengo un Page que se ve correctamente si lo instalo desde el Editor o Xcode pero cuando lo subo al Itunes Connect y lo habilito para TestFlight, al instalar la app desde TestFlight y ver esa pantalla pues no se visualiza de forma correcta, solo se ve como un contenedor gris.., me ha pasado en otro proyecto y lo unico que tienen en comun es que ambos widgets usan imagenes, pero tengo otros widgets con imagenes y se visualizan correctamente.

Utilizo Slivers como contenedores.
Al cargar los assets lo intente de dos formas.

- la general donde declaras la ruta y todo lo que este dentro de la ruta se puede utilizar:
  **assets/img/**
- La segunda fue especificando cada imagen.
  **assets/img/image1.png**
  **assets/img/image2.png**

Pero sigue sin poderse visualizar correctamente.

Widget visto al instalarlo desde el editor Xcode o Visual Studio Code.

[image: Widget visto al instalarlo desde el editor Xcode o Visual Studio Code.]

Widget visto al instalarlo desde TestFlight.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
            class MyPagePage extends StatelessWidget {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return MyPageFulPage();
              }
            }

            class MyPageFulPage extends StatefulWidget {
              @override
              _MyPageFulPageState createState() => _MyPageFulPageState();
            }

            class _MyPageFulPageState extends State<MyPageFulPage> {

              BuildContext context;
              final String _assetImagePath = 'assets/images/ic_no_image.png';
              String texto = ' ..... ';

              String _imagePath;

              @override
              void initState() {
                // TODO: implement initState
                super.initState();
                
              }
              

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context){
                this.context = context;
                  return Scaffold(
                      body: CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SilverAppBarTituloWidget(titulo: 'Titulo Page',),
                        _crearSilverList(),
                      ],
                      
                    ),
                    bottomNavigationBar: 
                      BotonGradientWidget(
                        texto: 'Siguiente',
                        marginBottom: 20,
                        onClick: (){
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/page02');
                        },
                      ),
                  );
              }

              _crearSilverList() {
                return SliverList(
                    
                    delegate: 
                      SliverChildListDelegate(
                        [              
                          SizedBox(height: 30,),
                          LabelInstructionsWidget(texto: texto,),       
                          SizedBox(height: 30,),  

                          _imagePath == null? 
                          _getImageFromAsset():
                          _getImageFromFile(_imagePath)
                          ,

                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: 'btnCamera',
                                onPressed: () => onClick(), 
                                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                              ) ,
                              _imagePath != null ? Container(width: 50,): Container(),
                            ],                
                          )                                                                          
                        ]            
                      )
                    );
              }

              onClick(){
                  _openCamera();
              }

              _openCamera()async{
                  final imagePath = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/camera');      

                  setState(() {                                
                    _imagePath = imagePath;
                  });

                  if(imagePath != null){        
                    print('Image path: $_imagePath');
                  }
              }

                Widget _getImageFromAsset() {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                  child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(
                            _assetImagePath,
                            //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            width: 60.0,
                            height: 60.0,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'No Image Available',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[350],
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              }

              Widget _getImageFromFile(String imagePath) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                  child: Image.file(
                    File(
                      imagePath,
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

Comment: la pantalla ploma es como la pantalla roja que te aparece en DEBUG, solo que en este caso es en de release, seguramente tienes errores en el layout, quizas permisos del teléfono, carga asíncrona, no hay conexíon http, etc

Comment: revisare, por que esa pantalla esta bien, la imagen en la camara es correcta, es una imagen gris, solo falla en el release.

Comment: declaraste los permisos de camara en el info.plist ?

Comment: A si es, pero ya vi en el debug y si sale un error de Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. aunque en debug si se visualiza correctamente, entonces ha de ser algo de esos como dices.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este problema en especifico es que no se deben subir errores de parentData a producción:

```
 Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
```

En este ejemplo en concreto el error que tenia era en mi Widget

```
LabelInstructionsWidget
```

tenia un Expanded como contenedor y los Expanded deben de ir en Columns o Rows, entonces solo cambie el Expanded por un Container para que el error desapareciera y al subirlo en TestFlight ahora si se visualiza de forma correcta.

Archivo erroneo:

```
                 Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    texto,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: HexColor('#646461')),
                    )
                ),
              );
```

Archivo correcto:

```
          Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: Text(
                  texto,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: HexColor('#646461')),
                  )
              );
```